# Ubuntu 18.04 + Gnome exit several times on logging in

Tags: 18.04, gnome, login

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 + Gnome desktop. Every time I reboot, I need to login 3+ times to enter the desktop.

After I input the username and password, the system goes back to the login screen after a flash of a black screen. I didn't get any information so I don't know what causes the problem.