# 18.04 flashes black screen and lock screen several times during login

Tags: 18.04, login, lock-screen, display-manager

This is an annoyance, but I thought I should post about it and see if anyone knows the solution.

I found:

- [GDM3 does not start in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1050672/457111)

But my situation is different as the laptop DOES eventually log in, it just takes a while (like 10 seconds or so, even if the user was already logged in and just locked).

I did try disabling Wayland, and it did not affect the problem (i.e. nothing improved).

I also found:

- [Ubuntu 18.04 + Gnome exit several times on logging in](https://askubuntu.com/q/1112504/457111)

But there are no answers; it's probably related since I've had to log in a second time at least once.

The usual case is that I will come to the laptop (which is a family laptop which rarely has fewer than three users logged in), swipe up and find the lock screen for another user, click "log in as another user", wait for a second or two while it switches to the main login window, click on my name, type in my password, press enter, and then **watch the screen blink nine times between a black screen and the login window (where I just put in my password) before it logs me in.**

This isn't just my account; all the users in the family have this experience.

The question: How can I make logins faster and get rid of the flashing black screen experience?

(I'm expecting more information will be needed to answer the question, but I'm not sure what information I should include.)

The hardware is a Lenovo ThinkPad L540.

Comment: I’ve switched to lightdm as this appears to be a bug in gdm.  Hopefully it will be fixed when 20.04 rolls around.

Comment: Nope, lightdm still has the issue.  However, it doesn’t freeze up when I exit a virtual terminal the way gdm does.

Comment: something in journal? `journalctl | egrep 'gnome-shell|gdm|input|lightdm'`

Comment: @nobody that produces thousands and thousands of lines of output.  I'll try looking at the recent errors next time I see the issue, but any more specific filter could be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I got same problem and tried to fix it for some time.

Try this one, this worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode FIXED
```

I found this solution here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2404491

Another user reported success by removing ubuntu dock extension

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

( I didn't tried this one jet, waiting for results after transperency-mode change )